# Bottom footer boostrap v3

Tags: footer, navbar

I'm creating a website, and I want a footer at the bottom of the website.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted">Copyright ©2015 Chalford Sports & Social Club | All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the basic CSS of bootstrap.

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

How can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html should be like

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">


      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
            this is footer
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and your `css` be like

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;

}


#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Just a concept. Play with the `classes` as you like.here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmx871py/)

Comment: Thanks, but i still have a little space at the bottom

Comment: Thanks, its work, i just need to remove the container class